# Spark Cassandra application always running mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Can we create a spark application using scala that will be in always running state. Like it executes the jobs periodically but driver program will keep on running so that I can access the RDD's created by jobs without storing it to permanent store (something similar to application context).

summary requirement is persisting RDD's in memory even after job is finished.

I am new to spark scala and looking for your guidance regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Spark program is just a normal Scala program, as long as the main method doesn't return, the application will keep running on the cluster. One way to do it is putting your Spark code in a loop that continuously process request.

```
while (!stop) {
  // poll() block until you put a new job into it.
  request = incomingJobQueue.poll()
  // Process the request with Spark
  // DO NOT call SparkContext.stop
  val result = ...
  outgoingQueue.put(result)      
}
```

The entire application shares the same SparkContext, so you can always access the persisted RDD. One thing to notice is to remember to `unpersist` a RDD when you no longer need it or memory will run out very fast. When this happens, RDD will be dropped from the cache using LRU policy, which might accidentally discards useful RDDs. Keeping the cache small also reduces GC overhead, making the program run faster.